# Python: capturing each thread details in individual log file

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I am performing web sanity for a couple of URLs and currently, we are logging the entire log details of these urls in a single log file (using logging module), but **it is required to capture log details of each url in a separate log file**.

Currently, I have 7 urls in a list and created 7 logging.txt files in a list.  Then, in a loop, I used the basicConfig() method for each of the logging.txt file and passed the corresponding url and logger object in the thread (please check the code below).

Upon running the script, I can find only one logging0.txt file generated with all the urls log details captured in it.  Clearly, passing the logger object as arg in thread do not perform what I thought it would.

```
log_files_here = ['logging0.txt','logging1.txt','logging2.txt','logging3.txt','logging4.txt','logging5.txt','logging6.txt']
urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6', 'url7']

for i in range(0, len(urls)):
    url = urls[i] 
    logfilepath = log_files_here[i]
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfilepath, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.INFO)
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

    print(f'Current logging file here {logfilepath} and loggere here is {logger}')
    logobject = getLogger(i)
    # Initiating thread here
    node_thread = threading.Thread(target=url_sanity, args=(url,logger))
    node_thread.start()  # starting the thread
    node_thread.join()
```

I further researched and created only one logger object and used RotatingFilehandler(), tested the below code and passed the logger object in the thread.

This generates 7 backup files with same INFO but not each of the url log details in 7 file.  Understand by passing the backUpCount arg takes backup only.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = RotatingFileHandler('my_log.log', maxBytes=2000, backupCount=7)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

So, this also doesnt solve the requirement.  Now, I have one log file generated with all the url log details in it, while all I want is each log file to be generated capturing each url (thread) information.
Please note that I cant provide any traceback error as I am getting the log details of these urls in a single log file.

Could you please assist on how I can capture the log details of each url in a separate log file?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're only configuring a single instance of the logger, as [`basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) only configures the root logger, even if you're looping that configuration X times, you're only configuring the same instance.

When you are doing `logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)` you're getting an instance that inherits from root logger and this has only one `fileHandler` configured.

An approach to solve the multi-file logging problem is to create as many *named loggers* as files you want, assigning each one of them a `fileHandler`.

This is achieved by using the naming system of the logging core. You can use, for example, the name of your url to get the logger you want to use.

Please check this example built from your code:

```
import logging
import threading

log_files_here = ['logging0.txt','logging1.txt','logging2.txt','logging3.txt','logging4.txt','logging5.txt','logging6.txt']
urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6', 'url7']


def configure_logging():
    """ Configuring all the logging instances with files-urls mapping"""
    for i in range(0, len(urls)):
        url = urls[i]
        logfilepath = log_files_here[i]
        # This will create and get a named urlX instance of the logger
        log = logging.getLogger(url)
        # NOTE: You can use a RotatingFileHandler here if fits better
        filehandler = logging.FileHandler(logfilepath, mode='a')
        log.addHandler(filehandler)
        # Feel free to parametrize this if you want different loglevel settings on your files.
        log.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def logger_worker(url):
    log = logging.getLogger(url)
    log.info(f"{url} logging! .")


def main():
    """ Testing current log settings"""
    configure_logging()

    for i in range(0, len(urls)):
        url = urls[i]
        node_thread = threading.Thread(target=logger_worker, args=(url,))
        node_thread.start()  # starting the thread
        node_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I added the logger= logging.getLogger(url) instead of logging.getLogger(__name__) and passed the logger object as arg along with the url in thread.  Still it didn't work.

Comment: I've updated the example to include the threading part. You need to ensure that you are getting the correct log instance before logging. You can get the log in the __main__ loop and pass it as argument, or (my choice) get the log inside the thread based on an argument